# Same Data if Close Modal in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I have this filter modal in which i can choose a country to show. Now, when i already have a selected country then i open the modal and close it without making a new selection, i still want that specific previously selected country to show only. Right now, all the items are displayed in this case. How can i fix this?

> modal.ts

```
closeModal(data) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data?data:null);
  }
```

> country.ts

```
myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {

          let selectedCountry = data;
          console.log(selectedCountry)
          if(selectedCountry === null || selectedCountry === 'all'){
            return this.modifiedItems = this.items
          }

          else {
            this.modifiedItems = this.items.filter((data) => {
              return data.location === selectedCountry
            })
          }
        });

        myModal.present();
```

Comment: What does the console log show after selecting a country? And u r using the variable name data twice within a similar scope which may be ambiguous hence creating issues

Comment: @TomG. After selecting a specific country, the onDismiss is called. AND if i dont select a specific country and just close the modal, the onDismiss is also called. So that is why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

When nothing is selected, does your data equals null or all the countries?
Anyhow, I think you should dismiss your modal with null when nothing is selected. Then, in your `onDidDismiss` check if data is not null before doing the rest.
You may also need to make `selectedCountry` global.